# Establish "needs attention" flag and/or review queue topic for links to defunct source code repos like CodePlex and Google Code

Tags: feature-request

I keep encountering defunct links to CodePlex and Google Code for example. Currently seems like the only way to know this is clicking the link.

I submit maybe Stack Overflow could implement some kind of either bot or one time query/marking tool that marks all the posts with defunct links to CodePlex/GoogleCode as "needs attention" for those interested to examine the question and fix them without directly having the exact question.

Perhaps a Review Queue topic for defunct links?

The logical evolution of that is Stack Overflow performing link checks that establish basic level "doesn't do 404" or something.

Comment: Do remember that if a question or answer cannot stand on its own without whatever's in the external link, it should be flagged/closed/deleted. Editing a working link into a post *usually* won't be of much value. A post author can create such a thing on an external site if they wish when they make the post, but if the link breaks, no one should feel *obligated* to fix it (just removing the broken link would be fine I think)

Comment: I wasn’t trying to obligate, only illustrate the breadth of the problem. As stackoverflow matures and older post links fall into oblivion, the problem will continue to grow

Comment: Besides we have an obvious problem here: CodePlex and google code are defunct. Every deep link into them is broken. Most moved into github

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't need its own flag, simply raising the issue on Meta is sufficient. Use the [clean-up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clean-up) tag if you need help fixing a bunch of posts.

Usually someone comes up with a search/query to use to find the posts that need editing.

An URL search can't determine whether the URL is valid but you would only need help cleaning something up if most/all of the relevant posts needed editing. It shouldn't be necessary to have a bot find only the bad links first.

In the case of something like CodePlex, which got archived, even links that are technically good could be improved. For example, there's a post linking to [the archive for BundleTransformer](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=bundletransformer) but it's active on GitHub.

Comment: A cleanup tag is insufficient IMO. how does one create a query in stack overflow that can enumerate all links then iterate them and check for validity?  I suspect there’s not one hence the request.